# For what $x$ does $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \sin (xn)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find the area of convergence for
>
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \sin (xn)$$

Its easy to see that for $ x \in (-1,1)$ it converges,
but not sure how to continue from there.

Comment: I believe it does not converge for $x=1,-1$

Comment: I don't see why the series converges for $x \in [-1, 1]$. Could you explain how you obtained this result?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Compare to geometric series.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Dirichlet test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the series to converge, you must have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n \sin (xn)=0$ for integer $n$. But this clearly does not hold if $|x| \ge 1$, unless $\sin (xn) = 0$ for all integer $n$. So the solutions are $x \in (-1, 1)$ and $x=k\pi$ for integer $k$. (Note that $x = 1, -1$ do not produce a convergent series)

Comment: $x=\pi$ makes every term zero, so series does converge.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that. Fixed.

Comment: Also I think it's worth explaining why the limit cannot be zero otherwise - in theory, values of $\sin(xn)$ could converge to zero really fast (I know it doesn't, but it's worth explaining why).

Comment: why it's clearly not converge for x=1 and |x|>1?

Comment: @Wojowu That would be because of the periodicity of the sine function. I can elaborate more if needed.

Comment: For $-1 < x < 1$, this converges to $x \sin(x) / [1 - 2 x \cos(x) + x^2]$.

Comment: @MihirSinghal The function $\sin(xn)$ is not generally periodic *as a function of* $n$, including when $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: It is not *"clearly the case"* that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(x n)$ fails to be zero without making further argument.

Comment: I did not say that it is periodic as a function of n; I said that $\sin x$ is periodic. That said, I agree that my answer is somewhat incomplete, and the below answer is better and should be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

For $|x|<1$ the series converges, per comparison with the geometric series $\sum |x|^n$.

For $x=k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, the serries converges trivailly because all summands are zero.

For all other $x$, the series diverges: Write $x=k\pi+\delta$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$, $|\delta|\le\frac\pi2$. Then for each $n$, one of $nx$, $(n+1)x$ differs by at least $\frac\delta2$ from the nearest multiple of $\pi$. Therefore one of the summands $x^n\sin (nx)$, $x^{n+1}\sin((n+1)x)$ is $\ge |x^n\sin\frac\delta 2|\ge \sin\frac{|\delta|}2>0$ in absolute value. This implies that $x^n\sin nx$ cannot converge to $0$ and the series diverges.